# How can I create a number of jetty run tasks in gradle?

Tags: jetty, gradle, embedded-jetty

I need create a number of different modes for running jetty in my gradle build.

They differ in system properties and classpath.

How can I do it using gradle jetty plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create multiple tasks of type `JettyRun`. To dynamically create different task instances you can use Groovy syntax sugar.

```
4.times { // this can be replaced by iterating over your different environment settings 
   task "jettyRun${it}(type:JettyRun) {
       // do you custom configuration here
   }
}
```

bb,
Rene

Comment: I have

    apply plugin: 'jetty'
   ...

    task runJettyTest1(type: JettyRun ){
   }

and receive ...

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':webapp'.
> Could not find property 'JettyRun' on project ':webapp'.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised. I would have expected that the JettyRun task is automatically imported. Can you try to import the JettyRun class explicitly in your build script by adding "import org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.JettyRun"

Comment: Yes, it helps, thank you. Now - how do I set system properties, web app root and classpath for each of such tasks inherited from JettyRun?

Comment: setting custom SystemProperties might cause issues as the jetty container is currently executed within the gradle jvm. there are plans to change that. The other options can be directly configured in the according JettyRun task. Have a look at the DSL documentation at http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.JettyRun.html for further details.

Comment: Thank you Rene, In my environment only one of those will be executed each time. So how do I set system properties?

Comment: well I think the only way to go atm is to set the property directly in your build jvm by simply doing "System.setProperty('key', 'value')". You can put this into a dofirst block of your jettyRun task.